# htaccess rewrite behavior (document root?)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a htaccess/apache Rewrite Problem, but it's a little bit trickier:

I have a domain like www.example.org and all content files are in

```
/var/www/www.example.org/content
```

every file must be accessed over an index.php which is saved in

```
/var/www/www.example.org/start1
```

so there is an .htaccess which rewrite everything to the index.php (no problem).

on apache is a host definied with:

```
ServerName  www.example.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/www.example.org/start1
```

that all works pretty fine, but now I have a second requirement:

there are sepcial files in content which should be accessed over another index.php(no way to use the same index.php as before),

so i put the second index.php in

```
/var/www/www.example.org/start2
```

and let the .htaccess rewrite everything to the new index.php.

in apache I defined an Alias

```
Alias /special /var/www/www.example.org/start2
```

when i now access www.example.org/special/file the .htaccess from /var/www/www.example.org/start2 is first in the rewrite log.
But it rewrite it to the index.php in the start1 folder not, as I expected, to the index.php of start2-folder.

I think its because of the document root, but I dont know what I can do. VHost is no option, because theres only one domain

Comment: Mind posting your current rewrite rules?

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
in start1 and start2 .htaccess
i tried also RewriteRule ^(.*) /var/www/www.example.org/start2/index.php

Answer (score 0):

In the start2 folder, you probably need to do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /special/index.php [L]
```

Because you've aliased `/special` to  `/var/www/www.example.org/start2`.